# Conditional rendering, "Encountered two children with the same key"

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to figure out how I can avoid this issue where momentarily all my keys are undefined. I'm building a realtime messaging application and there is a search input. By default, the list below search input will display a list of a user's conversation. As soon as you type something, it searches for people to that you can have a conversation with. But when you erase the user input, it'll default back to a user's list of conversations.

**Problem**

When I erase a user's input, all my keys are momentarily listed as undefined which then ends up breaking my conditional rendering. However, if I do not use keys, everything works as intended. How can I fix this issue where all my keys momentarily have the same key?

Shown below is the code of the component I'm working with.

```
const SidebarList = ({ type, route }) => {
    // Stores conversations or possible users to message
    const [list, setList] = useState({});

    // Retrieves all your conversations or users to message
    useEffect(() => {
        async function retrieveList() {
            const res = await fetch(route);
            const userData = await res.json();
            console.log(userData);
            setList(userData);
        }

        retrieveList();
    }, [route]);

    // List of conversations a user has
    let convoList = Object.keys(list).map((key) => {
        let hasAvatar;
        if (list[key].avatar) hasAvatar = true;
        else hasAvatar = false;
        return (
            <PreviewConvo
                key={`${list[key].conversationID}`}
                id={`${list[key].userID}`}
                avatar={hasAvatar}
                name={`${list[key].firstName} ${list[key].lastName}`}
            />
        );
    });

    // List of possible users a user can add
    let userList = Object.keys(list).map((key) => {
        let hasAvatar;
        if (list[key].avatar) hasAvatar = true;
        else hasAvatar = false;
        return (
            <PreviewConvo
                key={`${list[key]._id}`}
                id={`${list[key]._id}`}
                avatar={hasAvatar}
                name={`${list[key].firstName} ${list[key].lastName}`}
            />
        );
    });

    return <div>{type === "convo" ? convoList : userList}</div>;
};

export default SidebarList;
```

Comment: Well, this is potentially a code smell: "When I erase a user's input, all my keys are momentarily listed as undefined." That suggests to me there's a better way of doing this operation such that your keys never change to `undefined` momentarily.

Comment: Do you think it would be better to create a separate component? I thought about doing that but having 2 components that have the same code logic just doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: npm install uuid - I've used uuid to generate unique keys to render multiple components. Will never be undefined or a duplicate if I always generate a new key for each comment that is rendered. Not sure if this is a good approach, but it has worked.

Comment: I ended up creating an extra state to track my different lists which solved these issues. Thanks Nick for your feedback!